# Why outputs are different?

Tags: python

Hi I am a beginner with python and i don't know why I get these results using this two versions of code 
1.

```
q = input('write something with spaces')
print(q.split()[::-1])
```

RESULTS: 
write something hello everybody

['everybody', 'hello']

2.

```
q = input('write something')
q.split()
print(q[::-1])
```

RESULTS:

write something hello everybody

ydobyreve olleh

My question is: 
Why outputs are not the same ?

Thanks !

Comment: Because `q.split()` _does not modify `q` in-place_.

Comment: q stays the same and in the second example it hasn't been split. For the second code to have the same result as the first you'd have to change the second line to `q = q.split()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because q.split() does not change q in the second version
You should have done:

```
q = input('write something')
q = q.split()
print(q[::-1])
```